# Why does Caleb get locked down in Ex Machina?

Tags: plot-explanation, ex-machina

In the movie Ex Machina, Caleb reprograms the security system to unlock all doors when there is a power cut. When the 10PM power cut happens Ava gets out. In the end when Caleb is locked in, he tries to access the computer. At this time there is a power cut. Shouldn't this have triggered all the doors to be unlocked for him to escape? Instead we find Caleb smashing a locked door with a stool, which means the doors didn't unlock when the last power cut happens. They don't show Ava changing any security protocols or anything. How come the doors don't unlock?

Comment: Same question asked and answered on [SFF:SE](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93378/why-is-caleb-trapped-at-the-end-of-the-movie)

Comment: If Caleb knows up front that she's AI then it's not truly a Turing test is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a little clearer in the [screenplay](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=yvFMBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT141&lpg=PT141&dq=%22There%20is%20a%20red%20LED%20light%20by%20the%20keycard%20plate%22&source=bl&ots=aU6Fm3SipJ&sig=Bw3fCCf2bmrWAx6hCoZb4MVYn50&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zVGIVdf9IczfUe-egYgN&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22There%20is%20a%20red%20LED%20light%20by%20the%20keycard%20plate%22&f=false) that the computers shut down, not because the **power** had gone out, but **because Caleb attempted to use his own access card in the card reader**. Since the power was never out, the doors remained locked.

> He runs back to the monitors.   On them, AVA has reached the MAIN
>   ROOM.   She walks straight to the smashed window. And steps through.
>   CALEB sticks his card into the slot by NATHAN’S computer.   Instantly,
>   all the screens die. **Replaced by a single word.**
>
> **REJECTED**

[image]

Comment: ahh I see, thanks @Richard. Thought it was not a power cut because there was no machina.

Answer (score -4):

It is because Caleb programmed the room of Nathan to remain the only room locked after 10pm so that Nathan stays locked while they escape...

Comment: Isn't that because the key card would not be with Nathan? That's the reason why Caleb couldn't escape either. He didn't have Nathan's card.

Comment: No.....Nathans' room was to remain locked while Caleb and Ava escaped!

Comment: Caleb mentions only one change that he did with the protocols - instead of lock down of all doors, he inverts it to open all doors in case of a power failure.